# Why does Visual Studio want to check-out a File when opened?

Tags: visual-studio, version-control, visual-studio-2005, devforce, vcs-checkout

Why does Visual Studio want to check-out a File when opened?

I just double click the file to open it and Visual Studio wants to check it out.
I did not make any changes to it. I just opened it.

i.e. In Solution Explorer I double click ctlEmployeeEdit.vb and the first thing Visual Studio wants to do is check-out that file. I got VS set up to prompt me on check-out so I normally say no to the check-out and then the control will display.

We are using Visual Studion 2005 and Visual Source Safe 2005.

We have a solution of over a hundred files and it is only happening on a hand full of them but that hand full seems to be getting larger, almost a mouth full now. (Humm I wonder if a hand full is larger than a mouth full? But that question is for another posting.)

Also how can this be fixed?

Should I delete my local copy of the solution and do another "Get Latest" from Visual Source Safe when this happens?

I have the feeling some of you are going to say the way to fix this is to upgrade to a **REAL** Source Control producted. :)

**Edited:**

Some of the Third Party controls are:

1. DevExpress User Controls v8.3
2. IdeaBlade DevForce control

Answer (score 2):

This is not the default VS behavior.  It's almost certainly a 3rd party plugin that is doing something on file open that is ending up in a check out request.  What plugin's do you have installed?

There's also some designers that end up checking out files on accident when they are open.  Do you have any designers open?

Comment: Some of the Third Party controls are: DevExpress User Controls v8.3, 
IdeaBlade DevForce control

Comment: It's likely one or a combination of those controls that are causing the problem.  I don't know of any specific issue with those plugins though.

Comment: Infragistics controls also do this, they are forever modifying the licence files. It is very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this can happen with special types of files - specifically setup project files, but you're not being overly specific as to what kind of file it is?

At least that is how it works in TFS 2008.

Comment: I can confirm that source files (.cs, .xml, ...) do not get checked out until I actually go to change them in TFS 2008.  Sometimes it will check out the project file if I make a change to a file in a project.  I also have the project set up to allow concurrent checkouts.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any WinForms designers open? Sometimes VS.Net wants to change these files, this is usually the case when the designer can't load a custom control due to reference problems.